# DNS Records for HTTPS? NSONE, Namecheap, Hostmonster

Tags: ssl, dns, hosting, namecheap

sorry for the noob question.

Basically I have domains through Namecheap and my hosting is at Hostmonster.

I'd like to use the NSONE free DNS service. For a domain with http, I've already pointed the Namecheap nameservers to NSONE, and from NSONE pointing to the IP address of my hosting.

However I'm wondering whether its the same procedure for a domain I have which has a SSL certificate (https)?

I hope you understand my noob question.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a DNS record for HTTPS. A DNS record cares (among other things) about the mapping between the domain name and the IP address, and `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` are the same name and therefore have the same IP address. This means no changes need or can be done at the nameserver which are specific to https.